# Complex analysis $\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{d \theta}{(2-\sin \theta)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

how do I compute

$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{d \theta}{(2-\sin \theta)^2}$$

I tried substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$ but it just got very messy..

Comment: You could do this without complex analysis (although perhaps this is a problem for a complex analysis class). Interpreting the integrand as a polar function, we set $r(\theta) = 1/(2-\sin(\theta))$. Then the integral gives twice the area inside an ellipse, which isn't so bad to compute.

Comment: If you don't insist on complex analysis methods, you could use the [tangent half-angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't suggest an alternative method, but here are some suggestions for coping with the calculations after substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$.

If my algebra is correct, you should end up having to find the residue of
$$\frac{z}{(z^2-4iz-1)^2}$$
at its unique singular point inside the unit circle.  You will often find that it is simplest to do this kind of thing in symbolic form and then substitute back actual values at the end.  So, write the above as
$$\frac{z}{(z-\alpha)^2(z-\beta)^2}\ .$$
It is easy to find
$$\alpha=(2-\sqrt3)i\ ,\quad\beta=(2+\sqrt3)i\ ,$$
and the residue is
$$\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{(z-\beta)^2}\Bigg|_{z=\alpha}\ .$$
You can find this initially in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then simplify using the facts
$$\alpha-\beta=-2\sqrt3i\ ,\quad \alpha+\beta=4i\ .$$
It's not all that hard if you do it this way, just take it slowly and carefully.

Comment: thank you. this was very helpful.